# What does "catapulted forward" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching TV Show about business owners. and one business owner said this.

> Coronavirus has just catapulted everything forward about three years.

I get when someone catapulted forward, it means they jumped out of the car or something and going front. But in this case, I don't know whether it means everything(business) was supposed to happen right now, but it got delayed for 3 years or it was supposed to happen in 3 years but it happened 3 years earlier than expected.

Comment: More context would help. Is it referring to how jobs are moving online and home-based faster than would have happened without COVID?

Comment: I was asking that. Bc I didn't know. Whether it mean jobs are moving online and home-based faster or does every job or something getting slow and pushed away? But after I saw your comment I think it is about something happened faster.

Comment: Still not enough context. It probably means something like, "Changes that were on the way, like working from home and increased online purchasing, are happening now rather than a few years down the road." But can't be sure

Answer (score 2):

*To catapult something* means *to move it suddenly or at great speed*.

*Forward* shows direction, it moved us forward into the future.

The article argues that COVID-19 has pushed us out of our comfort zones and brought about changes we aren't prepared for and to which we need to quickly adjust ourselves (in order "to stay employable").

Answer (score 0):

A *[catapult](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/catapult)* is a device for throwing projectiles. So to *be catapulted* means to be thrown forward. It doesn't mean anything like jumping out of a car.

We could say

> Coronavirus has just thrown everything forward about three years.

Or perhaps

> Coronavirus has just hurled everything forward about three years.